# How to get all the keys in nested json object in java script

Tags: javascript

Hi below is my json string which is available in javascript

```
{
   "101":{"my":"1", "u":"4", "s":false, "isChecked":true},
   "102":{"my":"2", "u":"4", "s":false, "isChecked":false}
   .
   .
   .
   "1000":{"my":"999", "u":"888", "s":true, "isChecked":true}
}
```

Now -for example- I want to get the values of the `isChecked` property for each key:

- "101" "isChecked" is true
- "102" "isChecked" is false
- ...
- "1000" "isChecked" is true

Could please you share any useful snippet of code for this scenario?

Comment: what have you tried?  Isn't it just.. var obj = JSON.parse('your json string'); obj['101'].isChecked == true  ?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña looping is possible using `for in` as in `for (var key in object)`

Comment: or use Object.keys(jsonObj)  to get all the keys into an array

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all, rather about how to process arrays and objects in JavaScript. *How* you obtained the data (e.g. via JSON) is irrelevant to the problem.  See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` statement to go through the object:

```
var data = { /* your data here */ } 
for (var key in data) {
   console.log(key, data[key].isChecked);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tZzfb/